# Why are there cracks between my vinyl windows and the drywall?

Tags: cracks

This is a 5 year old house. Why are these cracks coming up in all my windows?

[image: this is a 5 year old house. why are these cracks coming up in all my windows?]

Comment: Check your contract. At 5 years, the builder may still be responsible for remedial work.

Comment: i bought house 2 years ago from original owner and sure sure how can i track the builder.. any idea?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. It would be in the documentation of the property transfer. Such as the original builder's guarantee really should have been a significant part of the registry/data search performed before you exchanged contracts. This sh\*t is *important*.

Comment: Looks normal to me.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like expansion and contraction of dissimilar materials. The caulking done when the home was built may have been done poorly and with low grade caulking. Now it has dried and the cracks (or spaces) are evident. The two surfaces should be cleaned and caulked with a quality grade paintable, flexible acrylic latex caulk to cover the cracks. Look for a lifetime rating of 30 or 40 years, such as DAP acrylic latex 40 or similar.

Comment: Be sure to use _paintable_ caulk there. Use as small a bead as possible for best appearance.

Comment: Did you mean "flexible" caulk, not "expandable"?

Comment: Yes flexible. Thanks for correcting the brain flub.

Comment: ok then I would perhaps add a typical example, such as a Urethane Acrylic caulk, it that' what you had in mind, to help the OP find it. Brands like to call all their products "high quality" and "flexible" if you know what I mean...

Comment: There...fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

New houses often have the framing get wet during construction and the framing drys over a few years.  When the framing dries it gets smaller and the caulking or paint separates where the materials meet.

Looks like it is time for some interior painting.